# How to validate doctrine type "json" with symfony json constraint in a form correctly?

Tags: json, symfony, symfony5

So, I'd like to enter some json into a form for it to be validated by symfonys json constraint:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Json(
 *     message = "variantJson field: invalid Json."
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
 */
private $variantJson = [];
```

The form looks kinda like this:

```
$builder
        ...
        ->add('variantJson', null, ['attr' => $style])
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            ...
            }
        })
    ;

    $builder->get('variantJson')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($jsonToString) {
                // transform the array to a string
                return json_encode($jsonToString);
            },
            function ($stringToJson) {
                // transform the string back to an array
                dump(json_decode($stringToJson, true));
                dump(json_last_error());
                  //1
                  return $stringToJson;
                  //2
                  return json_decode($stringToJson, true);
            }
        ))
    ;
```

The main problem is, that when I try to only return the json string in the ModelTransformer, I get this exception:

> Expected argument of type "array or null", "string" given at property
>   path "variantJson".

At the "**PropertyAccessor**"

And when I want to return as an array, I do the json_decode, and get a different error:

> Expected argument of type "string", "array" given

At the "**JsonValidator**".

My suspection is, both PropertyAccessor and JsonValidator are in serial, and both need different types.
I must be missing something. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Doctrine type JSON does indeed expect an array:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#json

This is useful if you have the need for an Array in your code and want to save that data in the database. The data gets converted to a JSON string before saving and back to an Array when retrieved.

If you don't need the array in your PHP code and your end-user is submitting JSON somehow that needs to be validated. You should probably just save it as a (LONG)TEXT.

Comment: But I need the array in the PHP. Should I just try to validate it myself and return it as array then in the ModelTransformer? I just don't get why the symfony json constraint is not compatible with the json doctrine property, they must have had something different in mind...

Comment: (By validating myself I mean to use the validator for it)

Comment: Well, it's two different things, the validator is purely for validating JSON strings, has nothing to do with saving or converting it. Doctrine JSON type is for saving "Arrays" in the database, it does so by converting it to JSON. 

You will have to pick the combination that works best for you. If the JSON is supplied by the user and can be faulty you should probably stick with the validation + TEXT field and convert it to an Array when you need to.